# How do you specify that an API method has no response body?

Tags: retrofit

I am trying to use Retrofit 2.0 and the converter-jackson module to consume an API.

I have a few GET methods to get the status of some objects and converting the received payload into the objects works fine.

I also have an endpoint that I need to PUT to in order to acknowledge that I have processed the objects returned to the GET request. This PUT method does not return a body, just a status of 200 if everything works or an appropriate error code.

I have tried a few different ways to specify the put method in my Retrofit interface with no success. I get an error like this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@1d5ef9ae; line: 1, column: 1]
```

if I specify the return type of the method as some object that I don't really expect to receive, like this:

```
@PUT('/acknowledgeStatus')
Call<String> acknowledgeStatus(@Body Acknowledgement idsToAcknowledge)
```

and I get errors like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class com.example.MyObject. Tried:
 * retrofit.DefaultCallAdapter$1
```

where `MyObject` is the object returned by one of my Retrofit API's other GET methods when I try to define the PUT method like either of these:

```
@PUT('/acknowledgeStatus')
Call acknowledgeStatus(@Body Acknowledgement idsToAcknowledge)

@PUT('/acknowledgeStatus')
Response acknowledgeStatus(@Body Acknowledgement idsToAcknowledge)
```

How can tell Retrofit not to expect a response body for this method and still have access to the response status, headers and other details?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As of the second beta release, you can use the return type of `Void`

```
@PUT('/acknowledgeStatus')
Call<Void> acknowledgeStatus(@Body Acknowledgement idsToAcknowledge)
```

The following still works, but might be less efficient --

Try telling it you want a `ResponseBody`.

```
@PUT('/acknowledgeStatus')
Call<ResponseBody> acknowledgeStatus(@Body Acknowledgement idsToAcknowledge)
```

that will give you access to the response status, etc, and the raw response body (if any).